# $|f''(x)|\leq 1$, $\exists\ x_1\neq x_2, \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$. Show that $|f(x)|\leq 1, \forall\ x\in [0,1].$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> $|f''(x)|\leq 1$, $\exists\ x_1\neq x_2, \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$. Show that $|f(x)|\leq 1, \forall\ x\in [0,1].$

If $x_1=0, x_2=1$, then Taylor expansion would help. But here we only know that $x_1\neq x_2$! What this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then by Rolle's theorem $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

If $f''$ is continuous then we have $ \left| f'(x) \right|=\left| \int_{c}^{x} f''(t)dt \right|\leq \left|x-c\right|$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Similarly ,  $ \left| f(x) \right|=\left| \int_{x_1}^{x} f'(t)dt \right|\leq | \int_{x_1}^{x}  \left| t-c \right| dt |\leq \frac{1}{2}(c-x_1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x-c)^2\leq 1 $.

Comment: Note that in order to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus $f'(x) = \int_c^x f''(x) dx$, the second derivative must be continuous, or at least Lebesgue integrable. – That's why I prefer to use the mean-value theorem, if possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: How do you get $| \int_{x_1}^{x}  \left| t-c \right| dt |= \frac{1}{2}(c-x_1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x-c)^2$? Perhaps you mean $\le$?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for remarks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ implies that $f'(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Now use the mean-value theorem twice: First,
$$
 f'(x) = f'(x_0) + (x-x_0) f''(\xi)
$$
shows that $|f'(x)| \le 1$ for  all $x \in [0, 1]$. Then
$$
 f(x) = f(x_1) + (x-x_1) f'(\eta)
$$ shows that $|f(x)| \le 1$ for  all $x \in [0, 1]$.

---

But a better estimate is possible, one can actually show that $|f(x)| < 1/2$:

For $c \in [0, 1]$, $c \ne x_1, x_2$, consider the function
$$
 g(x) = (c-x_1)(c-x_2)f(x) - (x-x_1)(x-x_2)f(c) \, .
$$
Then $g(x_1) = g(x_2) = g(c) = 0$, and repeated application of Rolle's theorem shows that $g''(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi$. It follows that
$$
 0 = g''(\xi) = (c-x_1)(c-x_2)f''(\xi)- 2 f(c)
$$
and therefore
$$
 |f(c)| = \left| \frac 12 (c-x_1)(c-x_2)f''(\xi)\right| < \frac 12 \, .
$$

This is the best possible bound, as can be seen by considering the functions $f_\epsilon(x) = \frac 12 x(x-\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ close to zero.

Comment: "Then $|f(x_0| \le 1/2$ follows from $|f''(x)|\leq 1$ and that $x_0$ has a distance of at most $1/2$ from one of $x_1$ or $x_2$", can you expatiate on how this follows?

Comment: @fwd: I have added more details.

Comment: For the accounts to work out, you can use $x_i\leq 1$ and $0\leq x_0$, and then you will have a majorization that is the same as the one required to demonstrate.

Comment: @fwd: I have rewritten the answer completely (and improved the estimate).